# BufferQueue has been abandoned: When playing video with TextureView

Tags: android, video, surfaceview, activity-lifecycle, textureview

Every time I pause my activity (actually Fragment) to go to another app, upon returning with onResume I try to resume the video playing but it does not play: I get a blank screen. Upon investigation, I see the following in the Logcat

```
E/BufferQueueProducer: [unnamed-23827-0] queueBuffer: BufferQueue has been abandoned
E/MediaPlayer: error (1, -38)
E/MediaPlayer: error (1, -38)
E/MediaPlayer: error (1, -38)
E/MediaPlayer: error (1, -38)
E/BufferQueueProducer: [unnamed-23827-0] connect(P): BufferQueue has been abandoned
```

Here is the code I call inside on resume

```
player.seekTo(mVideoSeekPosition);
player.start();
```

FYI: I have been trying to apply this answer to my case, but I can't: [What can I do when the BufferQueue has been abandoned?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22486762/what-can-i-do-when-the-bufferqueue-has-been-abandoned)

**UPDATE**

I struggled to go it alone, but I am still crashing. So I am posting the whole code for help

```
private void setupVideoPlayingSystem(View root) {
  textureView = (TextureView) root.findViewById(R.id.textureView);     
  textureView.setSurfaceTextureListener(this);
}               

@Override
public void onSurfaceTextureAvailable(SurfaceTexture surfaceTexture, int width, int height) {
  Log.d(TAG, "onSurfaceTextureAvailable");
  if (null == surface) {
    Log.d(TAG, "new surface");
    surface = new Surface(surfaceTexture);
    mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
    mediaPlayer.setSurface(surface);
    mediaPlayer.setLooping(false);
  }     
  /*     
  outstandingVideoRequest is IOU for orentation change (verifed: onResume before onSurfaceTextureAvailable)
  but for cold startup, must check mVideoUrl
  */     
  if (outstandingVideoRequest && null != mVideoUrl) {     
    outstandingVideoRequest = false;
         playNewVideo(mVideoUrl);
  }     
}          

@Override     
public void onSurfaceTextureSizeChanged(SurfaceTexture surface, int width, int height) {     
  Log.d(TAG, "onSurfaceTextureSizeChanged");
     }          

@Override
     public boolean onSurfaceTextureDestroyed(SurfaceTexture surface) {     
  Log.d(TAG, "onSurfaceTextureDestroyed");
  return false;//leave destruction for onDestroy     
}

@Override
public void onSurfaceTextureUpdated(SurfaceTexture surface) {         }     

    private void playNewVideo(String url) {         
      if (null == mediaPlayer || null == surface) {         
        Log.d(TAG, "playNewVideo not ready");
                 synchronized (outstandingVideoRequest) {
                   Log.d(TAG, "playNewVideo outstandingVideoRequest");
                    outstandingVideoRequest = true;
        }          
      } else {         
        try {         
          mediaPlayer.reset();         
          mediaPlayer.setDataSource(getContext(), Uri.parse(url));         
          mediaPlayer.setLooping(false);         
          mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();          
          mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {

            @Override         
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer player) {         
              Log.d(TAG, "onPrepared changeMediaPlayerDatasource");         
              onReadyToPlay(player);
            }         
          });         
       } catch (Exception e) {//IOException && IllegalStateException         
         Log.d(TAG, "textureview playNewVideo ERORR");         
         e.printStackTrace();         
       }                  
     }         
    }

  private void resumeVideoUponReturningFromAnotherActivity() {
             if (null == mediaPlayer || null == surface) {
                 Log.d(TAG, "resumeVideoUponReturningFromAnotherActivity outstandingVideoRequest");
                 outstandingVideoRequest = true;     
        } else {     
//            playNewVideo(mVideoUrl);
                 Log.d(TAG, "resumeVideoUponReturningFromAnotherActivity go NOW");
                 mediaPlayer.setSurface(surface);     
            onReadyToPlay(mediaPlayer);
             }          
    }          

    private void onReadyToPlay(MediaPlayer player) {     
        //play video     
        mProgressCircle.setVisibility(View.GONE);
             showVideoOverlayChildren();     
        if (0 == mVideoSeekPosition) {     
            Log.d(TAG, "onReadyToPlay start");
                 player.start();
             } else {     
            Log.d(TAG, "onReadyToPlay seek");
                 player.seekTo(mVideoSeekPosition);      
           player.start();
             }     
        mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                 @Override
                 public void run() {
                     Log.d(TAG, "postDelayed resumeVideo");     
                hideVideoOverlayChildren();
                 }     
        }, Constant.BEFORE_VIDEO_OVERLAY_DISAPPEAR);
         }

              private void destroyMediaPlayer() {
             if (null != mediaPlayer) {//move to video todo     
            mediaPlayer.stop();
                 mediaPlayer.release();     
            mediaPlayer = null;
             }     
        if (null != surface) {
                 surface.release();
                 surface = null;     
        }     
    }          

    private void pauseVideo() {
             if (null != mediaPlayer) {
                 Log.d(TAG, "pause");     
            mediaPlayer.pause();
                 mVideoSeekPosition = mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
             }     
    }

              private void stopVideo(){     
        if (null != mediaPlayer) {
                 Log.d(TAG, "stop video");
                 mediaPlayer.pause();
                 mVideoSeekPosition = mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
                 mediaPlayer.stop();
             }     
    }

@Override     public void onResume() {
         super.onResume();
         Log.d(TAG, "onResume");     
    mLocalBroadcastManager.registerReceiver(mVideoSelectionReceiver, mVideoSelectedIntentFilter);     
    resumeVideoUponReturningFromAnotherActivity();
          }
```

Comment: If the display surface is going away when switching activities then you'll need to call setDisplay() / setSurface() with the new Surface.

Comment: I can't figure it out. I put `mediaPlayer.setSurface(surface);` right before the seek portion it still didn't work. Plus I tried a few other stuff.

Comment: Did you pass it a new Surface from the new TextureView?

Answer (score 11):

I had the same problem when switched between activities and also had MediaPlayer(1971): Error (100,0). Solved it by adding these lines inside onSurfaceTextureDestroyed

```
    @Override
    public boolean onSurfaceTextureDestroyed(SurfaceTexture surface) {
        if (mediaPlayer != null) {
            mediaPlayer.stop();
            mediaPlayer.release();
            mediaPlayer = null;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

I find `setSurface(null)` is useful.

If you use a TextureView to display something, when `TextureView.SurfaceTextureListener` callback `onSurfaceTextureDestroyed` was called, you must stop use `SurfaceTexture/new Surface(SurfaceTexture)` binded by `camera2`, `MediaCodec` or `MediaPlayer`.

Like this

```
@Override
public boolean onSurfaceTextureDestroyed(SurfaceTexture surface) {
   mediaPlayer.setDisplayer(null);
   return false;//do not return true if you reuse it.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems there is a bug in your code:
in SurfaceTextureDestroyed() you did not reset surface or mediaPlayer. When resume, neither mediaPlayer nor surface is null, so in resumeVideoUponReturningFromAnotherActivity() set the surface and call start to play, but surface already become invalid because of previous SurfaceTextureDestroyed. That's why you get error.

To fix it, you should reset surface in callback SurfaceTextureDestroyed. When resume, rebuild surface in callback SurfaceTextureAvailable, set it to mediaPlayer and call start to play. The codes go like this:

```
public void onResume() {
   if (mSurface == null) {
      mResumeRequested = true;
      return;
   }
   mMediaPlayer.start();
}

@Override
public void onSurfaceTextureAvailable(SurfaceTexture surface, int width, int height) {
   mSurface = new Surface(surface);
   if (mMediaPlayer != null) {
      mMediaPlayer.setSurface(mSurface);
      if (mResumeRequested) {
         mMediaPlayer.start();
         mResumeRequested = false;
      }
   }
}

@Override
public boolean onSurfaceTextureDestroyed(SurfaceTexture surface) {
   mSurface = null;
   return false;
}
```

And you do not have to reset media player at all. If you reset, you have to re-instantiate it and re-buffering, which causes delay, this harms user experience because no delaying pause/resume is more desired.