# MediaPlayer cannot play video from url

Tags: android, video, android-mediaplayer, textureview

I am using a TextureView to play a video from my App-Engine server. I can play the video fine if I open the link in a browser. But MediaPlay has the following errors about file not found and then not being about to play the video

```
I/MediaPlayer: Need to enable context aware info
 E/MediaPlayer-JNI: QCMediaPlayer mediaplayer NOT present
 D/MediaPlayer: setDataSource IOException happend : 
 D/MediaPlayer: java.io.FileNotFoundException: No content provider: https://companycloud.appspot.com/watchvideo/?videoid=1234567771234567
 D/MediaPlayer:     at android.content.ContentResolver.openTypedAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:1074)
 D/MediaPlayer:     at android.content.ContentResolver.openAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:927)
 D/MediaPlayer:     at android.content.ContentResolver.openAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:854)
 D/MediaPlayer:     at android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(MediaPlayer.java:1085)
 D/MediaPlayer:     at android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(MediaPlayer.java:1059)
 D/MediaPlayer:     at com.company.app.android.fragment.VideoFragment.playNewVideo(VideoFragment.java:411)
 D/MediaPlayer:     at com.company.app.android.fragment.VideoFragment.access$400(VideoFragment.java:63)
 D/MediaPlayer:     at com.company.app.android.fragment.VideoFragment$1.onReceive(VideoFragment.java:120)
 D/MediaPlayer:     at android.support.v4.content.LocalBroadcastManager.executePendingBroadcasts(LocalBroadcastManager.java:297)
 D/MediaPlayer:     at android.support.v4.content.LocalBroadcastManager.access$000(LocalBroadcastManager.java:46)
 D/MediaPlayer:     at android.support.v4.content.LocalBroadcastManager$1.handleMessage(LocalBroadcastManager.java:116)
 D/MediaPlayer:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
 D/MediaPlayer:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
 D/MediaPlayer:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5837)
 D/MediaPlayer:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
 D/MediaPlayer:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
 D/MediaPlayer:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1388)
 D/MediaPlayer:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1183)
 D/MediaPlayer: Couldn't open file on client side, trying server side
10-24 12:25:26.665 6742-7036/com.company.app.android E/MediaPlayer: error (1, -2147483648)
10-24 12:25:26.685 6742-6742/com.company.app.android E/MediaPlayer: Error (1,-2147483648)
```

Comment: why not use a VideoView ?

Comment: I was having a lot of problem with the videoView so I switched. But certainly that is not the solution to the problem. Do you know that the TextureView cannot be made to work?

Answer (score 0):

Well I cant comment and since there isn't any reference code to look at, here are few suggestions:

1) 
The solution works for Android version 4.0 or higher.

Initialize the MedialPlayer object inside the `onSurfaceTextureAvailable()` method and put it inside the try/catch block.

**Parse the Uri. Since A Uri object is usually used to pass the reference of the content to a ContentProvider.**

```
@Override
public void onSurfaceTextureAvailable(SurfaceTexture surfaceTexture, int i, int i2) {
    Surface surface = new Surface(surfaceTexture);

    try {
        mMediaPlayer= new MediaPlayer(); 
        // parse the URL path
        mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(getApplicationContext(), Uri.parse(URL_PATH));
        mMediaPlayer.setSurface(surface);
        mMediaPlayer.setLooping(true);

        mMediaPlayer.prepareAsync();


        mMediaPlayer.setOnBufferingUpdateListener(this);
        mMediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(this);
        mMediaPlayer.setOnVideoSizeChangedListener(this);
        mMediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);

        // Play video when the media source is ready for playback.
        mMediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
                mediaPlayer.start();
            }
        });

    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        Log.d(TAG, e.getMessage());
    } catch (SecurityException e) {
        Log.d(TAG, e.getMessage());
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        Log.d(TAG, e.getMessage());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.d(TAG, e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Also for streams prefer using prepareAsync(), since it returns immediately, rather than blocking until enough data has been buffered.
call `MediaPlayer.prepareAsync()` method since you use constructor for creating MediaPlayer object.

Don't forget to do a memory cleanup once you are done playing video

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if (mMediaPlayer != null) {
        mMediaPlayer.stop();
        mMediaPlayer.release();
        mMediaPlayer = null;
    }
}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Sorry about the no code thing. It is here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33288303/bufferqueue-has-been-abandoned-when-playing-video-with-textureview. Also I tried modifying to your way and still got the same errors.