# BufferQueue has been abandoned Flutter

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart

Whenever there is a UI update, for example Loading/Waiting Screen or Google Maps Loading Screen

```
E/BufferQueueProducer(11055): [SurfaceTexture-0-11055-4] setAsyncMode: BufferQueue has been abandoned
```

keeps on coming in console its not doing any harm or error but its really hard to debug with this much rush in console

[image]

any help in hiding or removing it will be appreciated.

Using Android Studio : Android Studio Dolphin | 2021.3.1 Patch 1
Flutter Version : Channel stable, 3.3.8

Comment: similar question https://stackoverflow.com/a/57763152/15294308

Comment: On your Given Link answer explained "How t resolve error". As I already mentioned it is not an error it just a line that keeps comming in console and in given answer he clearly mentions that "This: E/BufferQueueProducer( 9243): [SurfaceTexture-0-9243-14] dequeueBuffer: BufferQueue has been abandoned will be still in debug terminal but it's not an error". I just want to get rid of it from console

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Select content you want to hide in Console.
2. Right click on selected Content
3. Select `Fold Lines Like This`

[image]

4. Click OK

[image]

All Done.